# sales tax python

Tags: python

They question is, Using a function give one instruction below that adds the sales tax of three items, item1, item2 and item3, and assigns the result to variable total_sales_tax

so far I have:

```
item1 = input(‘Enter price of the first item:’)
item2 = input(‘Enter price of the second item:’)
item3 = input(‘Enter price of the third item:’)
return total_sales_tax = (item1 * .06) + (item2 * .06) + (item3 * .06)
```

It isn't running properly.. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you say "It isn't running properly", it's very helpful if you give the *actual* error message, or incorrect output, that you are seeing. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using smart quotes (`‘’`) - are you writing your code in Word? Try this:

```
item1 = input('Enter price of the first item:')
item2 = input('Enter price of the second item:')
item3 = input('Enter price of the third item:')
return total_sales_tax = (item1 * .06) + (item2 * .06) + (item3 * .06)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the input function expects a valid python expression, and according to the Python Documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input), should not be used for general user input; raw_input should be used instead.

Additionally, raw_input will return a string, which will give you an error when you try to multiply it by a float, such as your tax value. You should cast the user input to a float before attempting to multiply it. Try this instead:

```
item1 = float(raw_input('Enter price of the first item:'))
item2 = float(raw_input('Enter price of the second item:'))
item3 = float(raw_input('Enter price of the third item:'))
tax = 0.06

total_sales_tax = item1 * tax + item2 * tax + item3 * tax

print total_sales_tax
```